# CRC in python, little Endian

Tags: python, crc, endianness

I need to calc CRC checksumme of binary file.
This file content CRC too and by comparing I find out when file was corrupted.

Bin file is something like long hex string

```
00200020 595A0008 ......
```

But CRC in file was calculated per integer(4.byte little Endian) like this

```
1.int -  0x20002000
2.int -  0x8000A559
```

How can I get the same result without switching bytes in python?
I was trying http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/ and played with reflect in, but I dont get the same result.

For this two bytes is correct crc **0xEF2B32F8**

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module. You can open a file and use the unpack read the data  in any format you want with any Endianess.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following code for calculating crc8:

```
acklist = [] # a list of your byte string data
x = 0xff
    crc = 0
    for i in range(len(acklist)):
        crc += int(acklist[i], 16) & x

print(crc)

crc = ~crc
crc += 1

crc1 = crc >> 8 & x
crc2 = crc & x
```

Comment: That is not a CRC.